# drivers for Dell Dimension 8200 Desktop?

Tags: dell

I am getting ready to install Ubuntu on my dekstop Dell Dimension 8200.  This is my first experience with Ubuntu.  Do I need to download any additional drivers?

Answer (score 0):

According to a post on the Ubuntu Forums, you need to select nomodeset before booting. Insert the CD, press the up and down arrow keys, select language, press F6 and select nomodeset with the arrow keys. Then select Install Ubuntu with the arrow keys and press enter, and you should be good to go.